# SQL Server : remove response with almost same date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query in SQL Server that looks like this.

```
SELECT   
    [ActionId], [CreationDate], [Description]     
FROM 
    [Action]
INNER JOIN
    People ON Action.personid = People.personid
WHERE
    datediff(mm, Action.creationdate, getdate()) = 1 
    AND People.typeofpersonid = 8
```

But now I would like to remove any responses that have a creationtime within a minute of another one.

So if response is currently

```
ActionId CreationDate                  Description
---------------------------------------------------------
510467   2015-04-07 11:21:02.030       Registered errand.
510468   2015-04-07 11:21:25.840       Email sent to:....
510477   2015-04-07 11:50:22.830       Registered errand.
```

I would like for the second row to not be returned.

Is there a smart way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT
    Action.ActionId,
    Action.CreationDate,
    Action.Description
FROM 
    Action
JOIN
(
    SELECT 
        ActionId, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CreationDate, 120), 16)
            ORDER BY CreationDate, ActionId
        ) AS row_num
    FROM 
        Action
    WHERE
        DATEDIFF(mm, CreationDate, GETDATE()) = 1 
) AS a2 ON (Action.ActionId = a2.ActionId AND a2.row_num = 1)
JOIN 
    People ON (Action.PersonDd = People.PersonId)
WHERE 
    DATEDIFF(mm, Action.CreationDate, GETDATE()) = 1 
    AND People.TypeOfPersonId = 8
```

Comment: Very good (even though I don't understand much of it)but it goes on the same minute instead of one minute a part.
Hate to be picky but it is a problem to me since they can be just a few seconds apart and still be on different minutes

Comment: Yup, sorry, I should have explicitly mentioned it. I could not think of a way to do it the way you are asking, this was my best approximation.

Comment: Maybe there is a better way to achieve your goal by incorporating data also from other columns (e.g filtering or grouping on Description or some substring of Description).

Comment: Yes. I used a version of this answer in the end. Changed the nr 16 to 15 to remove a bit more answers and changed the join on to:
ON (action.ActionId = a2.ActionId AND ( a2.row_num = 1 OR a2.Description not like '%Email sent%'   ))
Which means it only removes rows where description is a sent email.

This worked well enough for my needs, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
SELECT  [ActionId],   [CreationDate],    [Description]     
         FROM [Action]
         inner join People on Action.personid = People.personid
         where datediff(mm, Action.creationdate, getdate()) = 1 
         and      People.typeofpersonid=8

    AND  NOT EXISTS 
    (
    SELECT TOP 1 1
    FROM [Action] Ain
         inner join People Pin on Ain.personid = Pin.personid
         where datediff(mm, Ain.creationdate, getdate()) = 1 
         and      Pin.typeofpersonid=8
         AND datediff(mi, Ain.creationdate, Action.creationdate)<1
         AND Ain.ActionId <>Action.ActionId
    )
```

The general idea is that you check for existing rows, and if there is one, then you dont include it you query.

Comment: To me this just returned one row, the one with the latest date.

Comment: Well, sorry? I wil not do your work for you. Like I said, this is a general idea, of course it wont work. you need to adjust the query.

Comment: Well no need to take it personal. I havn't asked you to do anything as far as I know. I have however tried to work with that example for some time and failed.
This may or may not be useful information for someone else who reads this question.